# android custom popup box on listview item tab attach with each item position

Tags: android, android-listview

Is their any example available that similar like shows popup box or dialog box that popup up on itemClicklistener and attach with item position with 2 buttons on top and middle area is just like some inofroamtion and at the bottom of popup box also two more buttons. just like attach image.

[image]

Comment: you can use `PopupWindow` with custom layout like you showed in the image.

Comment: i need some examples references

Comment: look at this [ans][1], hope this will help



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20826026/793943

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on `Listview`'s `onItemClickListener`

```
View popupView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popupmenu, null);
                final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, true);
                popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popup.showAsDropDown(view);
                popup.update();
```

`R.layout.popupmenu` is the custom layout for your `PopupWindow`. The buttons can be referenced as

`Button add = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.bAddNew);`

and then implement `onClickListener`

Comment: thanks rohan kandwal, if i tap on last list item at the bottom on footer area we said then layout could not show complete. is their any way to auto adjust popup?

Comment: See this answer for adjusting the popup http://stackoverflow.com/a/18951503/1979347

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632842/get-absolute-view-position-in-listview

this helps me alot